# Can a callback function be set on a mailto form submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, callback, mailto

I want to submit a `mailto` form and attach a callback to the form submit.

This is what I'm doing:

```
$(document).on('click', '#mail_trigger', function (e) {
    // client form
    var form = $(this).closest('form'),
        first = "info",
        last = "some.com"
        mailto = "mailto:"+first+"@"+last+"?",
        subject = "subject=Website enquiry&",
        message = "body="+$('#msg_comment').val(),
        bcc = $('#msg_cc').is(':checked') ? "bcc=" + form.find('#msg_address').val() + "&" : "";

    // actual form to send (to prevent form inputs ending up in message)
    $(".actual_mailer").attr("action",mailto+bcc+subject+message).submit();
    $.mobile.changePage("thanks.html", {"transitions":"slide"});
});
```

I want to add the `$.mobile.changePage...` call to a callback function, but trying this:

```
$(".actual_mailer").attr("action",mailto+bcc+subject+message).submit(
    function(){
        $.mobile.changePage("thanks.html", {"transitions":"slide"});
});
```

Breaks the page without showing an error in the console.

**Question:**
Is it at all possible to add a callback function to a `mailto` form submit. If so, how would I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Use the callback function of the `submit()` method?

Comment: @BenM: have you tried with a mailto action ala `mailto:info@some.com`. Does not work it seems